# Cross compile problem?

Tags: c++, cross-compilation

I am trying to build applications for my Raspberry Pi using a cross compiler by using [crosstool-ng](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/). My build system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I tried building a test program, it works.

On build system:

```
$ cat > prog_without_so.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; return 0; }
^D
$ arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=c++0x  -lstdc++ -o prog_without_so prog_without_so.cpp
```

On Pi:

```
$ ./prog_without_so
Hello, world!
```

However, when I tried to run a program that uses shared libraries, it returns this:

On Pi:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="." ./prog_with_so 
./prog_with_so: error while loading shared libraries: librsmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Curious, I tried `ldd` and `file`:

On Pi:

```
$ ldd prog_with_so
    not a dynamic executable

$ file ./prog_with_so
./prog_with_so: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.3.0, not stripped
```

Also tried the same on the first program:

```
$ ldd prog_without_so
    not a dynamic executable

$ file ./prog_without_so
./prog_without_so: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.3.0, not stripped
```

I wasn't able to find anything new here.

What's going on? Is my cross-compiler incorrectly set up? Why does it fail only when the application depends on a shared library?

This is my source for the second program:

```
//somemath.h
#include <iostream>
class CSum {
    int _sum;
public:
    CSum(int i):_sum(i) {}
    CSum operator+=(int i);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const CSum& sum); // output;
};

//somemath.cpp
#include "somemath.h"

CSum CSum::operator+=(int i)
{
    _sum += i;
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const CSum& sum) // output
{
    out << "(" << sum._sum << ")";
    return out;
}

//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "somemath.h"

CSum sum(1);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc>1)
    {
        int n = 1;
        while(n<argc)
        {
            sum+=atoi(argv[n]);
            std::cout<< sum << " ";
            ++n;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    } 
    else
    {
        std::cout <<"Usage: " << argv[0] << " [2 3 4 ... ]\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how I compile and link them on my build system:

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared somemath.cpp -std=c++0x -fPIC -lstdc++ -o librsmath.so 
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.cpp -o prog_with_so -std=c++0x -L ./  -lstdc++ -lrsmath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found that crosstool-ng has provided some samples which can be used.

```
ct-ng list-samples
```

I selected the configuration for pi 2, which works very well. :-)

```
ct-ng armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf
ct-ng build
```